# Encountering issues when using a protocol based Enum

Tags: swift, enums, swift-protocols

A simplified version of what I currently have, taken from a Playground file I setup:

```
import Foundation
/// Simplified protocol here
protocol MyProtocol: CaseIterable {
    static var count: Int { get }

    var name: String { get }
}
/// Simplified extension. This works fine with app
extension MyProtocol {
    static var count: Int {
        return Self.allCases.count
    }
}
/// Simplified enum, this works fine as well
enum MyEnum: MyProtocol {
    case value

    var name: String {
        return "name"
    }
}
```

Using the following works as expected:

```
print(MyEnum.count) // 1
let myEnum = MyEnum.value
print(myEnum.name) // name
```

However, I would like to create an object that is initialized with `MyEnum`.

First, I attempted the following:

```
final class MyManager {
    private let myEnum: MyProtocol

    init(myEnum: MyProtocol) {
        self.myEnum = myEnum
    }
}
```

However, both spots where I use `MyProtocol` provide the following error:

> Protocol 'MyProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because
>   it has Self or associated type requirements

I then switched it up with the following that got rid of the error, but produces a new issue:

```
final class MyManager<MyProtocol> {
    private let myEnum: MyProtocol

    init(myEnum: MyProtocol) {
        self.myEnum = myEnum
    }
}
```

When I attempt to access properties for `myEnum`, they do not appear in Xcode:

[image]

I need to be able to access the properties defined in `MyProtocol`, but neither approach is working properly for me & I have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MyProtocol` generic is not the same as the `MyProtocol` protocol.  You need something like this

```
final class MyManager<MyP: MyProtocol> {
    private let myEnum: MyP

    init(myEnum: MyP) {
        self.myEnum = myEnum
        print(myEnum.name)
    }
}
```

I also want to point out that a better way to implement `count` is by extending `CaseIterable`

```
extension CaseIterable {
    static var count: Int {
        return Self.allCases.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I actually got to the same solution just now as well & will also use your count suggestion as well!